# Append to list in DynamoDB(C#)

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Dynamo table of US states and each state has a list of businesses. The structure is as follows:
`{"Name": {S: "Ohio"},"Businesses":{"L": [ { M: {"Name":{"S":"McDonalds"}}, { M: {"Name":{"S":"IHOP"}} ] }`

My goal is to write a function that can take a list of businesses and IF they don't exist already append them to the list of businesses, I have gotten this far:

```
public async Task UpdateStatesBusinessList(Buisness buisness)
{
    var dynamoRequest = new UpdateItemRequest
    {
        Key = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
        {
            {"Name", new AttributeValue{S = buisness.Name}}
        },
        ExpressionAttributeNames = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"#B", "Businesses" }
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
        {
            {":B", new AttributeValue{L = business.Businesses}};
        }
    }
}
```

```
Public class Business
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

We can pretend I have a hard coded list of businesses like:

```
BusinessList = new List<Business>
{ 
  new Buisness {Name = "Chilis"}, new Buisness {Name = "BurgerKing"},etc...
}
```

I know I need to use an update expression with SET and use the if_not_exists() with list_append(). I need help constructing the request because my ExpressionAttributeValue is not correct... Any advise would be great, I have looked through all the AWS documentation and countless websites and have not been able to get it to work.

Comment: What about using a string set (instead of a list) as the attribute type? That's your best path.

Comment: @hunterhacker - But OP has list of complex type, not just string.

Comment: Sure but can’t do what they want with a complex type. Hope they can adjust the schema to use a set.